# using plain javascript how to insert html before closing tag?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of HTML article tags that are dynamically generated. Some of the article tags have a class named "featured". I want to insert some HTML right before the closing article tag where the class is named "featured" using plain javascript.

```
<article class="list-item featured">
  ....
</article>

<article class="list-item">
  ....
</article>

<article class="list-item featured">
  ....
</article>

<article class="list-item">
  ....
</article>
```

I tried using something like, but it did not work.  I got an error: featuredItem.insertAdjacentHTML is not a function.   What syntax should I be using to do this?

```
  var featuredItem = document.getElementsByClassName("featured");
  featuredItem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div class="ribbon-featured"></div>');
```

Comment: `innerHTML += ...`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object containing 0 or more elements. You can't invoke `insertAdjacentHTML` on the *set* of returned elements, you need to pick one element from the set to manipulate its content.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object, so you can `forEach` through each array object with the *featured* class name as such:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("featured").forEach(featuredItem => {
  featuredItem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div class="ribbon-featured"></div>')
})
```

Comment: I get this error ReyHaynes document.getElementsByClassName(...).map is not a function

Comment: @user1669296, sorry about that. Forgot it returns an array-like object so you can use `forEach` instead of `map`. Code updated.